# designing web pages to look good in both IE6 and IE8 browsers

Tags: asp.net, css

in ASP.NET application, how to design the pages in such a way that they are displayed properly in both IE6 and IE8 browsers? I would like to minimise the CSS work that I need to do if there are any general guidelines to follow which will work in both browsers. I may still need to tweak here and there, but I want to reduce bulk of the work. Please let me know if there are any such guidelines.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to consider posting an example or two of more specific issues in order to get better help.

Comment: Start developing in IE8, or better yet, in a standards compliant browser such as Chrome, Safari, Firefox. From there, go and tackle IE6 with hacks and other stupid crap that it requires. Funnily enough, you CAN learn to code CSS for IE6 as well (with some exceptions). Last week, I started testing an existing application in IE6 to find that I only need 2 lines of code to fix. Get familiar with the quirks :)

Comment: @Marko: How exactly is IE8 not standards compliant? Admittedly, it's a browser I would not use when developing websites (simply due to lack of useful tools), but saying that it's not standards compliant goes too far.

Comment: Haha I knew someone would hit me up about that @BalusC. But have you run the Acid3 test in IE8? http://acid3.acidtests.org/

Comment: @Marko: IE8 is aimed to be CSS 2.1 compliant and it is. Acid3 fails in lot of other browsers as well.

Comment: @BalusC. Sorry for my ignorance but it must have something to do with my long-lasting hatred for IE. I once started writing a virus that would prevent users from running IE6. I wish I was a better programmer.

Comment: @Marko: I fully understand you :) Actually, I have had the same problem.

Comment: @BalusC, haha, shall we start a project on CodePlex? :)

Comment: thanks for all the replies, all the answers and comments are useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by making sure that basic layout of your page is working cross-browser. This can be quite trick, but the good news is that other people already did the heavy lifting for you. Just google for "one column", "three column", "holy grail" or whatever layout your are aiming for and you will find plenty of articles describing how to achieve it in any browser you want.

Starting for there, my suggestion is to code for IE8 and add hacks for IE6 when required. This should keep the hacks at a minimum since CSS that works in IE8 **usually** also works for Chrome, Firefox and the other decent browser.

Don't try to make your site pixel perfect across all browser, this will only drive you insane. Let your website "degrade gracefully" on the older browser. IE6 users won't care if the site don't have rounded corners or gradients anyway.

Using javascript to simulate modern CSS features in older browser is also a good idea. But I don't recommend using the ieX.js scripts. These scripts require too much CPU to run and can make your site unresponsive if your HTML is heavy.

Comment: I am developing against IE8, then checking it in IE6, but I found some differences, I guess making height and width percentage based than pixel based might do some trick, but I am not sure. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

I have been coding a recent project and used the ie7.js script from http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/. It works marvels at fixing IE 6 to a reasonable level. Then use this block to declare your body. (This part was ripped from html5boilerplate).

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <body class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <body class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <body class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <body class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <body> <!--<![endif]-->
```

You can how polish up any stray css my using the respective id like this...

```
#ie6 .element{
    //special stuff for ie6
}
```

The ie7.js script should save you quite a bit of time though.

Comment: there is another answer which says adding this script could cause performance issues, so I would try this as a last resort. thanks for the reply.

Comment: I will not lie this will cause a performance hit on your page when you load it there will be a visible delay. But using this script was an acceptable solution for my project and DRASTICALLY cut down my development time. The trick with <body> should not cause any performance issues however.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the following line to your  section it will force compatibility mode and  help minimize the amount of CSS you need to write:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" />
```

However, you probably won't get it perfect without writing custom CSS rules.