# How the asp.net web applications designed in IE6 work on IE8?

Tags: asp.net

I upgraded my current IE6 version to IE8 recently, but one of my Asp.net web application has some problem with the allignment of some lebels, textboxes etc in the web pages. The application is working fine, but only with the design issue(some textboxes and labels are not in a proper order as before in IE6). I have selected the compatability view in IE8, but still the issue is there. I have changed the 'Absolute' positioning of the fields in the web pages to 'Relative', but no use. Could somebody help me which would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [designing web pages to look good in both IE6 and IE8 browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944635/designing-web-pages-to-look-good-in-both-ie6-and-ie8-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET isn't responsible of letting your application show expected layout styling.

Whenever a web browser is upgraded - Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari... - there're some breaking changes because technology goes forward, or some Web standards compliance break old and wrong ways of doing things.

Your upgrade to Internet Explorer 8 or newer versions would force you to fix your Web application in any Web platform, even in ASP.NET.

Just inspect your CSS and markup, and try to fit to Internet Explorer 8 standards mode in order to get your Web site rocking again!

Comment: Too general answer that did not even answer to the question, nether help.

Comment: You're not right. Read other answers, and you'll find that all of them are in this direction. Please feel free to avoid downvoting because of nothing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer has something called [compatibity mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx) if your site has issues, this can be used as a stop gab. But you should off course fix the html/css so that it works on all the browers.

To find and fix the html/css issues, pass the url to one of the many html verifiers on the internet it will normally tell what you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

you could placing the following tag in the `head` section of the html-document:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE5" >
```

Causing the page to run in **[Quirks mode](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/quirksmode.html)**, what can *perhaps* fix the errors (or not ;). Depending on the (declared) doctype you could mess with several **[compatibility modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx)**

However, I encourage you to change your css in a compatible way. Perhaps by overruling the failing css-classes with **[conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#Version_Vectors)** and some **[stronger specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)**